# JQuery event accumulating

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the below to load a jQuery animated graph, however, upon subsequent clicks on the btnPreviewGraph, the results load time gets slower each time, I then realised that the events are accumulating. Can someone please advice on how to prevent the event from stacking up.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        $("#<%=btnPreviewGraph.ClientID%>").click(function () { 

            var Manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
            Manager.add_endRequest(function () { 
                $(".extras_result").each(function () { 
                    // get the width of the bar from the span html  
                    var length = $(this).find("span").html(); 
                    // Animate the width of the 'p' with a callback function  
                    $(this).find("p").animate({ 'width': length }, 700, function () { 
                        // once the bar animation has finished, fade in the results  
                        $(this).find("span").fadeIn(800); 
                    }); 
                }); 
            }); 
         });  

    </script>  


 <asp:Button ID="btnPreviewGraph" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  
                Text="Preview Qualified Statistics" CausesValidation="False"/> 
             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlPreviewChart" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
             <Triggers> 
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPreviewGraph" EventName="Click" /> 
             </Triggers> 
          <ContentTemplate> 
         <div class="row"> 
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="No. of qualified members" 
                        CssClass="label"> 
                    </asp:Label> 
              <br /><br /> 
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="extras_table" style="height: 120px"> 
  <tr> 
    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">Male</th> 
    <td><div class="extras_result"><p class="extras_p">&nbsp;<span><asp:Literal ID="litMaleStats" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
    </span></p></div></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">Female</th> 
    <td><div class="extras_result"><p class="extras_p">&nbsp;<span><asp:Literal ID="litFemaleStats" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></p></div></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <th class="extras_y-desc" scope="row">Unknown</th> 
    <td><div class="extras_result"><p class="extras_p">&nbsp;<span><asp:Literal ID="litUnknownStats" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></p></div></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td></td> 
    <td class="extras_x-desc"> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
             </div> 
         </ContentTemplate> 
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: is code shown being reloaded with ajax numerous times?

Comment: Is it just your animation which is queuing up? Or the whole function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function .off() - [jQuery API Documentation .off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#<%=btnPreviewGraph.ClientID%>").off('click');
    $("#<%=btnPreviewGraph.ClientID%>").on('click', function () { 
        var Manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
        Manager.add_endRequest(function () { 
            $(".extras_result").each(function () { 
                // get the width of the bar from the span html  
                var length = $(this).find("span").html(); 
                // Animate the width of the 'p' with a callback function  
                $(this).find("p").animate({ 'width': length }, 700, function () { 
                    // once the bar animation has finished, fade in the results  
                    $(this).find("span").fadeIn(800); 
                }); 
            }); 
         }); 
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be building up the endRequest events, so on every click, you're doing even more work.  You can remove those using .remove_endRequest.  Maybe try something like this, so it removes the event when the function is done.  This isn't perfect though, if you are able to click the button again before it is done, so you may want to disable it at the start of the function, then enable when done animating.

```
function animateBars() {
    $(".extras_result").each(function () { 
        // get the width of the bar from the span html  
        var length = $(this).find("span").html(); 
        // Animate the width of the 'p' with a callback function  
        $(this).find("p").animate({ 'width': length }, 700, function () { 
            // once the bar animation has finished, fade in the results  
            $(this).find("span").fadeIn(800); 
        }); 
        var Manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
        Manager.remove_endRequest(animateBars);
    }); 
}
$("#<%=btnPreviewGraph.ClientID%>").click(function () { 
    var Manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
    Manager.add_endRequest(animateBars);
});
```